# Помогите с кодировкой utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8

Через `curl` получаю строку, текст и сам ответ в utf-8, на выходе получаю
(`Ê ÷åðòó âñå! Áåðèñü è äåëàé - Ðè÷àðä Áðýíñîí`), варианты конвертации в `utf8` не помогли, через функцию определения кодировки определяет как utf8.
Подскажите как перевести строку в человеческий вид?

К сожалению код большой, не могу его показать, но опишу:
Получаю страницу через библиотеку [`php-curl-class`](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/tree/master/examples)
Далее получаю строку через `phpQuery`

Суть в том что есть 2 аналогичных сайта, с одного нормальная кодировка, а с другого нет, хотя два сайта в `utf8`

Вот часть кода

```
$multi_curl = new MultiCurl();
$multi_curl->setConnectTimeout(300);
$multi_curl->setTimeout(300);
$multi_curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$multi_curl->setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
$multi_curl->success(function($instance) use($competitor) {

    $sql_insert = [];
    $pq = phpQuery::newDocument($instance->response);

    $name = trim($pq->find('h1.name')->text()); // Result - Ê ÷åðòó âñå! Áåðèñü è äåëàé - Ðè÷àðä Áðýíñîí

    $pq->unloadDocument();
});

foreach ($source_links as $value) {
    $multi_curl->addGet($value['url']);
}

$multi_curl->start();
```

Comment: К сожалению это не реально.

Comment: Добавил часть кода

Comment: А куда вы выводите результат, где он не так выглядит ? На консоль или может в браузер, если в браузер, то какова кодировка страницы в которую вы это выводите, то же utf8 или может что то иное

Comment: вывдеите результат в файл и посмотрите в какой кодировке он на самом деле

Comment: Вывожу в консоль

Comment: А консоль в какой кодировке ?

Comment: Страница, которую получаю в кодировке utf-8

Comment: консоль в utf-8, у меня все в utf8

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73703/discussion-between-vadym-and-mike).

Comment: каким образом вы определили, что страница в utf-8, может тот сайт не правильно указывает кодировку. посмотрите вывод в шестнадцетиричном виде. в utf-8 русские буквы должны кодироваться двумя байтами, причем первый из них почти всегда 0x80 или 0x81

Comment: Для начала напишите верно вопрос :) "кодеровка"

Comment: Кодировка явно неправильная. Это [текст в CP1251, представленный символами CP1252](https://ideone.com/TL7P1i).

Answer (score 0):

Приходит ответ не в UTF-8

Для начала нужно заметить что как сказано и здесь и [How to detact the encoding using mb_detect_encoding correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846201/how-to-detact-the-encoding-using-mb-detect-encoding-correct)

Обнаружение кодирования не является точной «наукой», поэтому лучшее, что вы можете сделать, это избежать этого :)

Укажите

$multi_curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");

Потом после того какк вы получаете ответ можно проверить  кодировку ответа.

[mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)($s);

Но возможно кодировка будет выявлена неверно. Тогда попробуйте проверить разные варианты.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1251");

$s = 'Ê ÷åðòó âñå! Áåðèñü è äåëàé - Ðè÷àðä Áðýíñîí0';

echo mb_detect_encoding($s);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(utf8_decode($s));
```

Вывод:

```
UTF-8
string(45) "К черту все! Берись и делай - Ричард Брэнсон0"
```

Comment: У меня: UTF-8<pre>string(45) "Ƞ㟠¥ 桤欠瞭 Ѩ °"

Comment: где вы этот код запускаете?

Comment: Запускаю в консоле